# NextJS page only showing page in browser after scripts have been executed despite having the defer attribute

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to wrap my head around this. One of NextJS' advantages, being SSR, is to provide the HTML page already rendered by React in the server to the browser. The CSS is also inlined, so there shouldn't be a blocking CSS asset request as well.

The js scripts (main.js, page specific scripts) are injected into the head with the "defer" attribute, which (correct me if I'm wrong) should mean that the fetching does not block the HTML parsing, and executing the script should only happen after the HTML parsing is done.

However, when I made a sample project to test this out (with network throttling) the page is only shown after the main.js script has been fetched and executed (as you can see in the performance recording in chrome devtools in the image below, where I made the page background red to clearly see when it is first shown).

[Performance screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmAgK.png)

Am I missing something? I tried testing out a simple React SSR strategy from scratch and the HTML is shown correctly before the JS even finishes loading, when using the defer attribute for that script, which is why I can't figure out why this is happening when I use NextJS. Building and running with npm start instead of dev, seems to have the same effect (after increasing the throttling to account for smaller payloads).

Comment: Are you testing in development mode?

Comment: @Danila I see the same behavior whether i run "npm run dev" or "npm run build && npm start", the only difference is that it becomes a bit harder to see it happened in the built version due to the smaller js files which load rather fast. Still, in development, I don't see any script tags without defer so I don't get why the page rendering is waiting for them to load